# Updating two different documents in one line

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code for updating two users, both with different id .

```
User.update(
    { id: req.body.myId }, 
    {
        $addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.friendId }
    }, 
    function(err, user){

    }
);

User.update(
    { id: req.body.friendId }, 
    {
        $addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.myId }
    }, 
    function(err, user){

    }
);
```

I could not find anything in the docs aside from updating two things with the same attribute by setting `multi : true`  . However, the ids are different in this case, and it would be easier to error handle if I had them both being updated at once.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take advantage of parallel operations in `bluebird` or using `co`

You can do something like :

```
co(function* () {
  var res = yield {
    1: User.update({ id: req.body.myId }, { $addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.friendId }}).exec(),
    2: User.update({ id: req.body.friendId },{$addToSet: { FriendIds: req.body.myId }}).exec(),
  };
  console.log(res); // { 1: Upate_response_for_1 , 2: Upate_response_for_2 } 
}).catch(onerror);
```